# How do I transfer values from one form to another?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have 2 Forms. Form1 creates Form2 like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 AcqForm = new Form2();
        AcqForm.Show();
        string[] ret = AcqForm.fulldate;
        MessageBox.Show(ret[27]);
    }
}


public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public string[] fulldate; //Created in form 2
    close();              //Need to get this string back on or before close event
}
```

How should I go about doing this?

Comment: Are you saying you asked this *same question* yesterday on SO and it is now gone? Was it closed as a dupe? This is a fairly commonly asked question and it could have been merged with a more complete question (God knows this one isn't)...

Comment: You should name your controls.

Comment: Some people flagged it but somebody (an admin?) said it wasn't that similar as I already had code pertaining to a solution. I have since lost my code cause my question is gone :(. Can't see any evidence of it at all now.

Comment: May be this can be usefull http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41649154/adding-data-separate-data-grid-view/42478942#42478942

Answer (score 1):

You need to handle the Form2 instance's `FormClosed` event in the first form and access the public properties.

Comment: Will the variables still be accessible after closing the form? Also how would I do this?

Comment: Those are _fields_, not variables.  Yes, they will; closing a form does not affect the class instance.  You can get the form instance by casting the `FormClosed` handler's `sender` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Using this snippet, you can get a little knowledge on it.

in **Form1**:

```
using(Form2 form2 = new Form2()) 
{
  if(form2.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) 
  {
    MessagBox.Show(form2.fulldate);
  }
}
```

In **Form2**:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public string[] fulldate {get; set;} // Create a Property

    void CloseForm()
    {
         fulldate = "valueToReturn";
         DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want `button3_Click` to wait until `AcqForm` is closed before accessing `fulldate`, you'll first have to change `AcqForm.Show();` to `AcqForm. ShowDialog();`. (`Show()` doesn't wait for it to close.)

As for the `fulldate` field – it will be accessible even after the form closes because the form still exist. SLaks' remark about it being a 'field' means that we have different names for different types of 'variables'. What you have declared in the class (without `get` and `set`) is called a field. A variable in a method is called a 'variable'.

If you still want to do something when `AcqForm` closes, do this:

In Form1's constructor, before the `AcqForm. ShowDialog();`:

```
AcqForm.FormClosing += AcqForm_FormClosing;
```

And in Form1's class:

```
void AcqForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    //Whatever will be here will be done when the form is closing.
    //Use 'FormClosed' for doing things AFTER the form has closed.
}
```