# How to transfer value from one Form to another?

Tags: c#, winforms, class, oop

Ok Here is what I want. I have created a Class

```
public class docname
    {
        private string doctname;

        public string Doctname
        {
            get { return doctname; }
            set { doctname = value; }
        }
    }
```

and I have used it in a form

```
public string name;
docname dc = new docname();
dc.Doctname = name;
```

and when I check the value in another form I get a null value. Whats the reason behind this?

I am a beginner at C#.

Comment: When do you check the value in the other form? Responding to which event?

Comment: I use the loadevent to check the value but it shows me null when debugged.

Comment: in here name is not assign any value. so it shows as null. next case is in ur second form if u create new instance then u cant see earlier value. if u need to see it in second form as well then u need to make it as static

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I transfer values from one form to another?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9146931/how-do-i-transfer-values-from-one-form-to-another)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, in your code sample, you're not actually assigning anything to the `public string name` variable, so it will be null until you assign a value to it.  Assuming that's just a typo, you need to make sure that both of your forms are referring to the same instance of your `DocName` class (only create a `new DocName()` once in your code, and then pass that reference to both forms).

```
Form myForm1    = new Form();
Form myForm2    = new Form();
DocName dn      = new DocName();
myForm1.docName = dn;
myForm2.docName = dn;
dn.DoctName     = "SomeDocumentName.txt";

MessageBox.Show(myForm1.docName.DoctName);  // "SomeDocumentName.txt"
MessageBox.Show(myForm2.docName.DoctName);  // "SomeDocumentName.txt"
```

Because there is only one instance of your DoctName class, the property of that class will persist regardless of which form is calling it.

Answer (score 0):

public string name; <---
name = "blah"; <--- extra code
docname dc = new docname();
dc.Doctname = name;

Well, according to your code, the variable called "name" is null.

Comment: can you explain how can this help me?

Comment: According to your code, the variable "name" is just declared and given no value. You have to assign a value to name. Example: name = "whatever"; Otherwise the default value of name is null.