# Adding data separate data grid view

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I want to add data in 2 data gridview but they are in separate form how will i do it? The `datagridview1` is in `form1` and the `datagridview2` is in `form2`. Because in `form1` they cant see the data `gridview2` because it is on the other form.

Comment: Can you elaborate more?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this ... In form 1 create a property

```
private static Form1 instance1;
public string propertyForm1;
public static Form1 Instance1
{
    get
    {
        if (instance1 == null)
            instance1 = new Form1();

        return instance1;
    }
}
```

And, in Form2

```
private static Form1 instance2;
public string propertyForm2;
public static Form2 Instance2
{
    get
    {
        if (instance2 == null)
            instance2 = new Form2();

        return instance2;
    }
}
```

Now you can access this property in either of any **Form1** or **Form2** or any Forms/Classes within your project like this...

```
Form1.Instance.propertyForm1 = "your assigned value from form2";
Form2.Instance.propertyForm2 = "your assigned value from form1";
```

Hope this helps you. And, dont forget to mark as answer if this worked for you.